# angular not adding hash to ng-href for non supported browsers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ng-href attached to a link like

```
ng-href="{{post.btn.url}}"
```

the value of this would then generate as:

```
ng-href="/news/some-post"
```

For browsers which do not support html5 mode these links do not work because they need a #.

Testing in IE9 the hash is not added, do I have to check all href's myself and add the hash or is there an inbuilt angular method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular has the `{{hash}}` markup which you can add to the end of your `ng-href` to add the #

```
ng-href="{{hash}}/{{post.btn.url}}"
```

Source https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref